# How to connect to my heroku database from localhost?

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I'm new in django and trying to connect to my heroku database from my localhosted django app.

I've followed the instructions on heroku website but it's seems django won't understand that i'm trying to access an external database.

i get this error

```
   relation "myAppName_user" does not exist
     LINE 1: INSERT INTO "myAppName_user" ("title", "content") VALUES 
    ('Beat...
```

However i never created or never intented to create a table named myAppName_user

I'm just trying to access the table `user` in my heroku postgres db but i don't know why it tries with `myAppName_user`

i just explicitly added `myAppName` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` config as django throws an error if it's not the case.

My DATABASE config :

```
      DATABASES = {
        'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
          'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
         }
        }
       DATABASES['default'] =  
      dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://xxxxx')
```

I want to test my database from my localhost. I'm doing this easily with `Node JS` but i can't find the solution in django.

Any suggestions ?

**EDIT**

```
  from __future__ import unicode_literals

  from django.db import models

  class Fruits(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   content = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Comment: Which database is being used from the configs, cause I can see both, sqlite3 and postgres used? Also do you have models or anything?

Comment: postgres is the database i want to use. I've added my model in my post

Comment: Did you create a database, did you run `manage.py make migrations` `manage.py migrate` ?

Comment: You can install more user-friendly tool like `pgAdmin` and connect to remote db to check if the actual tables are created

Comment: i've already created my database on heroku. No, i didn't make `manage.py make migrations` and `manage.py migrate` . I'm new in django but if i understand i don't want to migrate my data, i just want to access it from localhost. I'm still in development stage.

Comment: These commands do not migrate data, they create required migrations, that define database schema. To be more precise, make migrations scans your models and collects any changes made to db schema and migrate actually goes and executes those queries in the database.

Comment: The error you got shows exactly that the table doesn't exist in the database, so I assume you haven't applied schema changes (migrated) to db

Comment: I just did 'makemigrations` etc. but i still have the same errors.

Comment: did you also do migrate?

Comment: yes i did both of them. No changes

Comment: for debugging I would suggest using regular way to set up db without third-party libraries _dj_database_url_